# "Message Queuing" Folder missing in "Services and Applications" node in Computer Management

Tags: message-queue, msmq

I turned on the MSMQ service in "Turn Windows Features On or Off" window. But I am not seeing the Message Queuing Folder in the "Service and Applications" node in "Computer Management". Therefore, not able to actually use MSMQ. Please Help..

Comment: Domain member server or workgroup?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run Services.msc and start the Message Queuing service in order to see it in Computer Management.